# Exclude weekends Low events Calendar

Tags: low-events

Is it Possible to exclude weekends from the {exp:low_events:calendar} tag?
Weekends is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the current version (v1.4.1). Will make a note of adding something like a `{is_weekend}` variable to the tag, so you can use that in a conditional.

Comment: I did this if statement for now.. {if {day_url format="%w"} == "0" OR {day_url format="%w"} == "6"}{/if} but that tag would be great!

Comment: That'd work. However, if you're on EE 2.9 or up, I'd be careful with that syntax, as that might throw an error due to EE's new conditional parser.

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.9. I'm not getting an error though, should i be? Is there a better way i could get the same result? Cheers.